# How to compile Libav enabling the verbose build output?

Tags: gcc, libav

I would like to compile Libav but making visible all the detailed output of the gcc compilation process.
Currently all I can get is a very simple list of instructions like this:

```
CC   libavformat/a64.o 
CC   libavformat/aacdec.o
CC   libavformat/ac3dec.o
CC   libavformat/act.o
CC   libavformat/adtsenc.o
CC   libavformat/adxdec.o
...
```

Any hint to get all the compilation flags and parameters used for every file?

Answer (score 0):

In the Makefile located in the Libav directory, you must comment the values for the variables BRIEF and SILENT, just like this:

```
BRIEF  = # CC HOSTCC HOSTLD AS YASM AR LD
SILENT = # DEPCC DEPHOSTCC DEPAS DEPYASM RANLIB RM STRIP
```